# Spring batch spring jpa error CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction IllegalStateException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am new to Spring. I am trying to migrate data from one database(Oracle) schema to another database(Oracle) schema. I tried to achieve this using Spring Boot 2.1.3 +Spring JPA + Spring Batch

Here is my code

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.db2db;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class },scanBasePackages = "com.db2db.configuration")
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.yaml

```
datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@<oracle server host>:<server_name>
    username: source
    password: xxxxx
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
second-datasource:
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@<oracle server host>:<server_name>
  username: destination
  password: xxxxxx
  driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

jpa:
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: none
  properties:
    hibernate:
      show_sql: false
      use_sql_comments: false
      format_sql: false
```

pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data JPA, default tomcat pool, exclude it -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ons</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Repositories

```
package com.db2db.source.repo;

import com.db2db.source.entity.SrcFirmBrokerEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface ReadFromSrcBrokerRepo extends JpaRepository<SrcFirmBrokerEntity, String> {
}
```

```
package com.db2db.destination.repo;


import com.db2db.destination.entity.DestFirmBrokerEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface WriteToDestBrokerRepo extends JpaRepository<DestFirmBrokerEntity, String> {

}
```

Entities

```
package com.db2db.source.entity;

@Entity
@Table(name="SOURCE_TABLE")
public class SrcFirmBrokerEntity implements Serializable {
...
}
```

```
package com.db2db.destination.entity;

@Entity
@Table(name="DEST_TABLE")
public class DestFirmBrokerEntity implements Serializable {
...
}
```

BatchConfiguration

```
package com.db2db.configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private WriteToDestBrokerRepo writeToDestBrokerRepo;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private ReadFromSrcBrokerRepo readFromSrcBrokerRepo;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;


    @Bean
    public Job importBrokersJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
        return jobs.get("importBrokersJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return steps.get("databaseToDatabaseStep")
                .<SrcFirmBrokerEntity, DestFirmBrokerEntity>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public BrokerItemProcessor processor() {
        return new BrokerItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public RepositoryItemReader<SrcFirmBrokerEntity> reader() {
        Map<String, Sort.Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
        RepositoryItemReader<SrcFirmBrokerEntity> reader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
        reader.setPageSize(10);
        reader.setRepository(readFromSrcBrokerRepo);
        reader.setMethodName("findAll");
        reader.setSort(sorts);
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public RepositoryItemWriter<DestFirmBrokerEntity> writer() {
        RepositoryItemWriter<DestFirmBrokerEntity> writer = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
        writer.setRepository(writeToDestBrokerRepo);
        writer.setMethodName("save");
        return writer;
    }

}
```

```
package com.db2db.configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.db2db.destination.repo",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "destEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "destTransactionManager"
)
public class DestDBConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean destEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(destDatasource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[] { "com.db2db.destination.entity" });
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("jpa.database-platform"));
        em.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource destDatasource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                env.getProperty("second-datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("second-datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("second-datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("second-datasource.password"));
        return  dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager destTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(destEntityManager().getObject());
    }
}
```

```
package com.db2db.configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.db2db.source.repo",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "srcEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "srcTransactionManager"
)
public class SrcDBConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean srcEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(srcDatasource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[] { "com.db2db.source.entity" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("jpa.database-platform"));
        em.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource srcDatasource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                env.getProperty("datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("datasource.password"));
        return  dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager srcTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(srcEntityManager().getObject());
    }
}
```

```
package com.db2db.configuration;

@Component
public class JobCompletionNotificationListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompletionNotificationListener.class);

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public JobCompletionNotificationListener(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        if(jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            log.info("!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results");
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to start the DemoApplication I am getting

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@50fa5938] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@59e43e8c] bound to thread [main]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:446) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:280) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemReader.doInvoke(RepositoryItemReader.java:256) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemReader.doPageRead(RepositoryItemReader.java:219) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemReader.doRead(RepositoryItemReader.java:163) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:92) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:94) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:161) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:119) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:113) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:203) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:399) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:214) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:186) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:172) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:166) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.db2db.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@50fa5938] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@59e43e8c] bound to thread [main]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:193) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 70 common frames omitted

2019-04-19 13:18:59.030  INFO 14388 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=importBrokersJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=5}] and the following status: [FAILED]
```

Appreciate any help in resolving this issue

Comment: I had fixed NoSuchBeanDefinitionException. This is due to the incorrect package location of repo in SrcDBConfig & DestDBConfig. The basePackages = should be `basePackages = "com.db2db.source.repo" & basePackages = "com.db2db.destination.repo"` in SrcDBConfig & DestDBConfig instead of `"com.db2db.source.entity.repo" & basePackages = "com.db2db.destination.entity.repo"`

Comment: But now I am getting the following exception  ```org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@50fa5938] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@59e43e8c] bound to thread [main]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:446) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to autowire a `ReadFromSrcBrokerRepo` in your `BatchConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

   // ...

   @Autowired
   @Lazy
   private ReadFromSrcBrokerRepo readFromSrcBrokerRepo;

   // ...
}
```

But there is no bean of that type declared in your application context. You need to declare such bean so that Spring can inject it in your config class. Same thing should be done for `writeToDestBrokerRepo`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not sure if that is the issue. I have even added a bean that implements the interfaces ReadFromSrcBrokerRepo and another one that implements WriteToDestBrokerRepo. I still get the same error

Comment: In that case, please update the question and show how you added them.

Comment: basePackage was pointing to incorrect repo location. Hence that error. I had resolved that error. Now, I am facing another issue. Please check the ticket description

Comment: By default, Spring Batch will use a `DataSourceTransactionManager` which is not aware of your JPA configuration. You need to make your `BatchConfiguration` class extend `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and override the `getTransactionManager` method by returning your `JpaTransactionManager`.

Comment: I am creating those in SrcDBConfig & DestDBConfig